# Laravel - Is there a cleaner way to do hasMany relationships without 2 loops?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the latest version of Laravel.

I have 2 MySQL tables, called `"authors"` and `"articles"`.

I have 2 authors, `"John"` and `"Sam"`, `John` has 2 articles, `Sam` has 1, The articles have a `"user_id"` column with the `ID` of the authors.

In order to display the  `Authors` and their `Articles`, I have to do 2 loops

```
@foreach($authors as $author)


// Here the author names are displayed
    {{$author->name}}

// I have to do this loop so I can show the articles of the Author
    @foreach($author->article as $article)
   <h3> {{$article->name}} </h3>

    @endforeach


@endforeach
```

Incase you need it, here is my Author Model:

```
class Author extends Model
{
    //

    public function article(){

        return $this->hasMany("App\Article", "user_id");

    }
}
```

I am mainly asking if there is a built in way to do this cleaner.

Comment: Why not retrieve all articles and eager load their author? Relationships work both ways.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you could do the following:

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
    {{$article->author->name}}
    <h3>{{$article->name}}</h3>
@endforeach
```

In order for this to work, you must declare the reverse of the relationship in the Article model like this:

```
class Article extends Model
{

    public function author(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Author", "user_id");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is lazyloaded. I would advise to eagerload the authors in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

As you have many more authors and articles this query will get very expensive and slow. I am not sure how your UI is showing the authors and articles information but I would think about having a page that shows a list of authors (but doesn't show their articles). And then let each author have a detail page. In the author-details page you could then list all of the articles which would be quick and efficient to query based on the author's id. This will help your site be cleaner and your queries more efficient.

Comment: This doesn't feel like an answer - more like a code critique.

Comment: It is a cleaner way to do the hasmany relationship. Instead of doing multiple hasmany relationships at one time in a loop, you would be guaranteed to only use one.